# ContentControls in Word Template not allowing editing

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I am pulling my hair out over content controls and templates in Word 2010. Here's the situation:

I have a .docx document (*not* saved in Compatibility Mode) with a number of content controls. I set them up the way I want them. I select the entire document and, in the Developer tab, group the controls together as per [this page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/create-forms-that-users-complete-or-print-in-word-HA101848148.aspx) to protect the doc. Testing my document, I can fill out the content controls—select from dropdowns, toggle checkboxes, pick dates, enter text, etc. Because of the protection, I cannot edit anything *except* the content of the controls, which is exactly what I desire.

For the heck of it, I open the VBA editor and, in the Immediate window, run this line of code:

```
?activedocument.contentcontrols.count
```

It gives me back 173 as the count.

I save my doc as a .dotx template.

Now, if I just open the template itself, I can fill out the content controls as before, I cannot edit the rest of the doc, and the count of the controls in the template is the same as in the document it was created from: 173.

But if I create a *new* document based on the template, I cannot add content to the controls. I cannot select anything from the dropdowns or enter text in the text fields or click checkboxes or anything else I am expecting to be able to do. My placeholder texts show but when I click on the controls, nothing happens. I can, however, edit the rest of the document's content, which I shouldn't be able to do.

If I get the count of content controls in the new document, it gives me back 0. Yet clearly something is still there in my doc, since I can see the placeholder text for the controls.

I'm obviously missing something, but what? How can I get this to work the way I need it to work?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what your problem is. When you create a template (*.dotx), you're supposed to double-click the template each time you want to use it; Word will automatically make a copy and ask you to save to a new location when you save; this is how templates work. Double-clicking a template opens the template as a new document. I don't know what "New document based on a template" does, but I suspect it's for copying a theme or something.

Comment: Creating a new document based on a template: either a) double-clicking the template, or b) selecting New and then choosing the template. Both create a new Word document using the template as, well, a template. Versus opening the .dotx file itself.